# Drag and drop url links(of products) between apps in android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, android-intent, drag-and-drop, deep-linking

Suppose am browsing products in amazon or flip-kart mobile apps. 
Is it possible to drag the links and drop them in my app.

Can this be done if I can open these apps in my app?

I know deep-linking helps to navigate between apps. But to do that, first I need to have those product links dropped into mine.

Any documentation or sample code would help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can copy and paste but there´s no such a way as in windows (and so) when you can drag, hold it on top of the task bar button for a while and drop it on another application.

Handling the share intent must be the best approach http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Comment: Thanks. It's given in the documentation that the app can share/send (using share icon) the url/image/test to the receiver app.

Comment: Is it possible to execute other apps(eg., amazon) in an app(call it app1) so when you click on share the link/image it's sent to the underlying app1 without showing the list of shareable apps.

Comment: it depends on user settings, she can set one of the applications as a default editor for that intent (notice that the system asks in the dialog something like Open? Open Always?)